# Bot gives same error message for any input given for a give command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an economy bot and I am making a *give* command. I have it set up so that you can type `>give @whoever 5` and the bot will take 5 out of your wallet and add 5 to the other person's wallet. But even if I have enough money to give to someone, the bot says I don't have that much money to give.

[image]

as you can see above, I have 200 in my account, but if I try to give 200 or 50, etc. They bot responds with:

[image]

**Code**:

```
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, member : discord.Member, amount=None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  await open_account(member)

  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Please enter the amount that you want to give!")
    return

  users = await get_bank_data()
  user = member
  bal = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

  amount = int(amount)

  if amount < 1:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your amount needs to be larger than 0!")
    return
  if amount > bal:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You do not have enough money in your wallet to do this!")
    return
  if amount < bal:
    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,"wallet")
    await update_bank(member,amount,"wallet")
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You just gave `{amount}` Ulti Coins to {member.name}!")
```

I even have a return statement after `if amount > bal:` but that seems not to work. How can I get my bot to know that I actually have enough to give?

Comment: Can you add the exact command which you are calling which results in the bot sending "You do not have enough..."?

Comment: @JacobLee It's `>give @member (any number)` Any number that i give except 0 and below, even if i have enough money, it gives me that error.

Comment: Has the dictionary containing all the user wallet data been modified at all? I.e., currently, is the data the bot is using _right now_ identical to the data provided?

Comment: I have not changed it since.

Comment: And just to confirm, the bot has not modified it, correct?

Comment: not since i posted this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is just that you are trying to get the wallet data for the wrong user. The bot checks if the user mentioned has enough currency in their wallet. However, the bot should be checking if the user who invoked the command has enough currency.

Thus, the code should look something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, member : discord.Member, amount=None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)

    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Please enter the amount that you want to give!")
        return

    users = await get_bank_data()
    bal = users[str(ctx.author.id)]["wallet"]   # Use 'ctx.author' instead of 'member'

    amount = int(amount)

    if amount < 1:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your amount needs to be larger than 0!")
        return
    elif amount > bal:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You do not have enough money in your wallet to do this!")
        return
    elif amount <= bal:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, -amount, "wallet")
        await update_bank(member, amount, "wallet")
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You just gave `{amount}` Ulti Coins to {member.name}!")
```